# Filtering in a group using Linq and EF and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a Linq query like so, that picks up all duplicates in the table..

```
            var duplicates = entities.TableName.GroupBy(item => new { item.Field1, item.Field2 })
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .SelectMany(g => g)
                            .ToList();
```

How do I get to filter on another column in the table, namely Field3 that is of type datetime and want all rows that have datetime in between yesterday ( ie today -1) and tomorrow (ie today + 1)..

So in effect, I want all duplicates that have Field1 and Field2 common, and in them, I want all records that have Field3 that is of type datetime and once which falls b/w yesterday and tomorrow

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a Where clause before the GroupBy clause:

```
entities.TableName.Where(x => x > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).GroupBy(...)
```

There may be an issue with the way I have written the Where clause due to some issues EF has with certain types of DateTime functions, in that case you may need to use the functions in the [Entity Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) library.

Comment: Let me get back to you on this. in the middle of something.. cheers